# Php framework Phalcon dont save sessions

Tags: php, session, frameworks, phalcon

I try to create application in php phalcon.

I use demo application INVO in php5.6, debian8, mysql.

Phalcon dont save session :(

In SecurityPlugin.php i have:

```
public function beforeDispatch(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $auth = $this->session->get('auth');
```

`var_dump($auth)` is `null` everytime :(

Comment: Have you registered the session service and started it?

Comment: Did you also check the `session` section of your php.ini file?

Comment: i have default php.ini from debian8 and php5.6, how i can check session section?

Comment: in xampp and php5.5 phalcon work correctly, sb help?